# Is this nested function problem solvable in C?

Tags: c, recursion, nested

Given g(x) = cos(log(2.21-x)) and that x = 0.99, estimate the value given by the nested g(g(g(x)... equation as the nesting approaches infinity (you don't have to actually go to infinity, but just set up a way to recurse this nesting n times or so).

I've tried some basic stuff like g(x) = cos(log(2.21-x))
and then creating a for loop defined by g(x) = g(g(x)). None of this works.

In these attempts I've gotten end of void errors and overflow errors. If anyone can figure out if this question is viable in C, even though C doesn't support "nested" functions, I will be amazed and very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive solution:

```
// assuming g(double x) is already defined and returning a double value

double get_g_x_to_n(double x, int n) {
    if (n > 1) 
        return g (get_g_x_to_n(x, n - 1);
    return g(x);
}

get_g_x_to_n(0.99, 1024);
```

Iterative solution:

```
// assuming g(double x) is already defined and returning a double value

double get_g_x_to_n(double x, int n) {
    double cur_operand = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
        cur_operand = g(cur_operand);
    }
    return cur_operand
}

get_g_x_to_n(0.99, 1024);
```

Comment: I prefer the iterative approach over a recursive solution, but the question did state *"...set up a way to recurse this nesting n times or so..."*. Hopefully that isn't a hard constraint.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It wasn't a hard constraint, I moreso added that because I'm trying to improve my recursive function skills. For the sake of learning, I would be very curious how you can solve this iteratively as well, especially if you think it's more efficient or preferable.

Comment: The solution above is an iterative solution as `get_g_x_to_n` does not call itself again within the body of the function. While there are some problems where recursive functions provide an elegant solution (like factorial or mergesort), every recursive call requires setting up a full function stack for the function call and if the number of recursive calls exhausts your stack space, Welcome to StackOverflow... (that is why iterative solutions are preferred, but if the number of recursive calls is not excessive, they are fine)